# Spring IoC. Конфигурация с помощью аннотации @Component, не работает((

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

Поставил аннотацию @Component над классом Cat:

```java
@Component ("catBean")
public class Cat implements Pet {...
```

В applicationContext3.xml создал сканер:

```xml
.......<context:component-scan base-package="ru.klimenko.spring.spring_course3"/>
    </beans>
```

В main создал бин mayCat  который должен маркироваться по  метке catBean:

```java
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext3.xml");
    Cat mayCat = context.getBean("catBean", Cat.class);
            mayCat.say();
            context.close();
```

Выдаёт ошибку((((

```
.......12:38:49.933 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'catBean' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:892)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1138)
        at ru.klimenko.spring.spring_course3.ConfigWithAnnotations1.main(ConfigWithAnnotations1.java:9)
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

В чем проблема? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: исключительно любопытства ради - а зачем конфигурировать с помощью xml, чем авторам курса (или вам) аннотации не угодили?

Comment: Слушаю скаченный курс, преподаватель упомянул, что в дальнейшем можно конфигурировать без xml, от простого к сложному, пока так((.

Comment: Похоже что проблема в конфигурации spring containera приложите полностью ваш applicationContext3

Comment: Вот,- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
  <context:component-scan base-package="ru.klimenko.spring.spring_course3"/>
</beans> нач-ый код я уже исполь.

Comment: в для других конфигураций все работало

Comment: Собрал проектик с Вашим кодом - все работает. Проверьте, тот ли пакет Вы сканируете (в нем ли или "ниже" лежит Cat.class)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, адрес пакета уже много раз перепроверял((, [github] (https://github.com/AxeAnton/spring_course3.2/tree/master/src/main). Может что то еще?

Answer (score 0):

У меня проблема абсолютно такая же, в этом видео все блоки для **pom.xml** были версии **5.2.8**, я взял более свежую версию **6.0.9** и все заработало, попробуйте.